# How to configure Google Cloud DNS for an AWS Load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-dns, aws-elb

I have an AWS load balancer. AWS assigns a DNA name like:
data-vm-190.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com

When I try to create a DNS CNAME record in Google Cloud, I get this error:
"Record data must be in the format server-1.example.com"

How can I get past this?

Comment: Did you put a dot at the end of the DNS name? for example `example.com.`

Comment: @JohnHanley, can you post this as an answer so that other community members can find it as a useful answer?

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to append a dot (`.`) to the record name.

Adding a dot (period or `.`) at the end of a domain name declares a fully qualified domain name. Without the trailing dot, some DNS servers will treat the name as relative to the zone name.

In the hierarchy of the domain name system, the root servers are named `.`. The domain `com` is a child of the root servers. The fully qualified name for `com` is `com.`. Popular usage dropped the trailing root servers (dropped the `.`) but DNS still treats that character as important.